# Что такое SQL Transactions, Transaction Isolation Levels?

Tags: sql

Что такое SQL Transactions, Transaction Isolation Levels?

Comment: наконец-то - продуманный, детальный, понятный вопрос!

Comment: Что конкретно непонятно? [Транзакция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)), [Уровень изолированности транзакций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D3%F0%EE%E2%E5%ED%FC_%E8%E7%EE%EB%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%ED%EE%F1%F2%E8_%F2%F0%E0%ED%E7%E0%EA%F6%E8%E9)

Comment: вопрос мне ясен, мне непонятен ответ.

Comment: Как то не совсем понятно Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability, может если бы на примере то яснее было бы. Типа сделал INSERT и  UPDATE и Commit добавил в конце и это уже транзакция?)

Comment: Начало - BeginTrans

Comment: Начало - BeginTrans (изменения)  RollBackTrans - откат или CommitTrans - завершение. Применяется когда следует сделать ряд взаимосвязанных изменений, и при невыполнении одного из них требуется сохранить исходные значения - откатить (и повторить). Транзакции могут быть вложенными  (Transaction Isolation Levels).      Например, 2 человека имеют доступ к одному счету. Можно попытаться снять все деньги одновременно. Но за счет транзакции, которая вызывается сразу и заканчивается списанием денег со счета, такой фокус не пройдет.

Answer (score 3):

Транзакция, если по-простому - это совокупность неких действий, причем такая, что либо все эти действия выполняются успешно, либо ни одно не выполняется вообще.

Простой (и классический) пример: допустим, у вас есть банковский счет, на котором лежит аж целых сто рублей. Вы захотели финансово помочь организации по спасению камчатских поползней, и перевели пятьдесят рублей на ее счет. Так вот перевод денег с вашего счета на счет этой организации и будет транзакцией, которая состоит из двух операций: уменьшение баланса вашего счета на пятьдесят рублей и увеличение баланса их счета на те же пятьдесят рублей. Для обеспечения целостности данных нужно чтобы обе операции были выполнены успешно, либо не были выполнены вообще, ведь если деньги с вашего счета будут списаны, но не поступят на счет организации, то такой перевод нельзя будет считать успешным, точно также он не будет корректным, если средства у вас не спишутся, а у организации - начислятся (ни вы, ни они вероятно не будут против такого развития событий, но ваш банк скорее всего этот аукцион невиданной щедрости не поддержит, рискуя на этом обанкротиться)

Соответственно, транзакция в sql - это последовательность операторов, которая либо выполняется целиком, либо целиком же откатывается. (почитайте про ключевые слова TRANSACTION, COMMIT,  ROLLBACK)

Пару слов об уровнях изоляции. При одновременном выполнении нескольких транзакций возникает проблема доступа к данным, которые меняются внутри транзакций. Допустим, транзакция перевода ваших денег списала у вас со счета те же самые 50 рублей. При этом с данными вашего счета в тот же момент времени работает какая-то другая транзакция (допустим, кто-то прислал вам 100 рублей). Логично было бы предположить, что после этих двух операций у вас на счете будет 150 рублей (-50 в пользу поползней, остаток 50 руб, затем  +100 от таинственного благотворителя, итого 150). Но проблема в том, что транзакции выполнялись одновременно, и обе считают, что изначально на вашем счету было 100 рублей (и они, черт возьми, по-своему правы). Тем самым, окончательная сумма на вашем счету зависит от того, какая из них выполнится раньше. Если первая, то у вас будет 200 рублей, если вторая - то всего лишь 50. Это лишь один пример возможных проблем (эта ситуация называется "потерянное обновление"), но есть и ряд других способов поломать данные.

Во избежание подобных казусов придуманы уровни изоляции транзакций, которые определяют, как именно несогласованные данные могут быть использованы другими транзакциями. Стандарт SQL-92 предполагает 4 таких уровня в порядке возрастания силы: Read uncommitted, Read committed, Repeatable read, Serializable. Чем более  сильным является уровень изоляции, тем надежнее он обеспечивает согласованность данных (и тем сильнее он влияет на производительность)

Подробнее - в соответствующей литературе

Answer (score 2):

Transaction - это просто группа объединенных логически операций, все результаты выполнения которых или все вместе фиксируются, или откатываются.

Transaction Isolation Levels - это про решение проблем чтения данных при конкуррентных транзакциях. Т.е. когда в рамках одной транзакции мы читаем те же данные, которые другая транзакция в это же время изменяет. Есть 4 уровня изоляции, каждый из которых решает 1 связанную с этим проблему + проблемы всех предыдущих уровней:

| # | Уровень изоляции | Решаемая проблема | Описание проблемы |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Read Uncommited | Lost Update | Прочитанные данные сформированы только последней из параллельных транзакций. Влияние остальных транзакций в данных не учтено |
| 2 | Read Commited | Dirty Read | Прочитанные данные были изменены транзакцией, которая затем была откачена |
| 3 | Repeatable Read | Non-repeatable Read | При повторном чтении тех же данных данные отличаются т.к. были изменены другой транзакцией в промежутке между чтениями |
| 4 | Serialization | Phantom Read | Повторная выборка данных по тем же параметрам отличается от первой, т.к. данные в промежутке между чтениями были изменены другой транзакцией |

- Уровни изоляции относятся к слою БД.
- Уровни изоляции - это компромисс между точностью данных и производительностью: более высокий уровень -> выше точность, но ниже скорость.
- В БД по умолчанию обычно выставлен Read Commited (PostgreSQL) или Repeatable Read (MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

ну вот тут вроде несложным языком описано

### http://www.osp.ru/pcworld/2009/07/9708191/

Наиболее простой вариант известен всем: один пользователь записывает информацию на уровне записи таблицы, а другой пытается ее прочитать. При отсутствии изоляции второй пользователь может прочитать данные незавершенной транзакции. Ситуация качественно усложняется, если изменениям (модификации, вставке, удалению) подвержена не одна запись, а несколько, возможно, даже в разных таблицах.

Прежде чем приступить к экспериментам на практике, давайте кратко перечислим особенности уровней изоляции согласно стандарту ANSI SQL-92.

**Незавершенное (черновое) чтение (read uncommitted)** — минимальный уровень изоляции гарантирует только физическую целостность при записи данных. Процессы-читатели могут считывать данные незавершенной транзакции процесса-писателя.

**Подтвержденное чтение (read committed)** — процессы-читатели не могут считывать данные незавершенной транзакции, но процессы-писатели могут изменять уже прочитанные читателем данные.

**Повторяемое чтение (repeatable read)** — повторное чтение данных вернет те же значения, что были и в начале транзакции. При этом процессы-писатели могут вставлять новые записи, имеющие статус фантома при незавершенной транзакции.

**Сериализуемость (serializable)** — максимальный уровень изоляции, гарантирует неизменяемость данных другими процессами до завершения транзакции.

**Моментальный срез (snapshot)** — данный вид изоляции не входит в рекомендации стандарта SQL 92, но он реализован во многих СУБД. Процессы-читатели не ждут завершения транзакций писателей, а считывают данные, точнее их версию, по состоянию на момент начала своей транзакции

Comment: Избегайте ответов-ссылок. Приводите в ответе основные моменты из материала по ссылке. Ссылка может протухнуть, а выдержка останется.